# Force analysis in a compound pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

At 4:56 of [this video](https://youtu.be/FNOfxJxceIM?t=296) on compound pulley systems with the following schematic set up:

[image]

The professor does a force analysis of the forces on the pulley A , and strangely (for me) , he finds that there is tension acting vertically at two diametrically opposite ends of the pulley.. but why does it specifically act there?  Why does tension not push the pulley down for the region where the rope curves around the pulley ?

Comment: He didn't show the upholding force of the string hanging the pulley A.

Comment: I mean yeah that's implicit but it doesn't answer my question @ytlu . My question is about why the semicircular section of rope has causes no tension forces on the pulley

Comment: If no friction is assumed, the string has an uniform tension everywhere. In each infinitesimal segment of the string in the semicircle. The two forces at the end of each segment equal and in opposite direction, therfore cancled.

Comment: Could you show a picture @ytlu

Comment: @Buraian do you mean that **why are tensions vertically down and not at some angles ?**

Comment: The tension in the curved part does push the pulley down and the resultant of this is 2T, that acts as T on either side of the pulley. Take an infinitesimal portion of the rope where it curves and write the equations and integrate.

Comment: @Buraian, like why is it acting at only that place? The location of application is relevant for thinking about torque calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no frictions between the rope and the wheel of pulley. Therefore, the wheel will not rotate, and the rope slips over the wheel frictionlessly.

Consider a finite segment of the rope between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, the total force acting on this segment of the rope (see the Figure):

[image]

$$
  \vec{F}_{total}(\theta_1 \to \theta_2) = \vec{T}_1 + \vec{T}_2 + \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \vec{N}(\theta) d \theta = 0; 
$$

where the vectors $\vec{T}_1$ and $\vec{T}_2$ are the draging forces from th rest of the rope ( in the tangential direction), and $\vec{N}(\theta)$ is the normal force per angle exerted from the wheel to this arc of rope. The normal force may be a function of angle. Since the mass of rope is neglected, the total foce has to be zero.

Then, we focus on the infinitesmal segment of rope betweem angle $\theta_2$ and $\theta_2 + d \theta$:
$$
   d\vec{F}({\theta_2}) =  \vec{F}_{total} (\theta_1 \to \theta_2 + d\theta) - \vec{F}_{total}(\theta_1 \to \theta_2) = \frac{\partial \vec{F}_{total}(\theta_1 \to \theta_2) }{\partial \theta_2} d \theta = 0.
$$
The force on the infinitesmal segment should also vanish, as detailed balance of the force.

The force $\vec{T}_1$ depends only one $\theta_1$, thus vanishes as derived by  $\theta_2$ :

$$
  \frac{d \vec{T}_2 (\theta_2) }{d \theta_2} + \vec{N}(\theta_2) = 0.
$$

Since $ \vec{T}_2$ is in the tangential direction, $  \vec{T}_2 = T \hat{\theta}_2$. The derivative of a unit tangential vector renders a unit vector in negative $r$-direction, $-\hat{r}$.  This render the normal force at angle $\theta_2$ to be:
$$
   \vec{N}(\theta_2) = - T \frac{d \hat{\theta_2}}{d\theta_2} = T \hat{r}. 
$$

Surprisingly, the magnitude of the normal force per angle is a constant independent of the angle, equals to tension of the rope.

Comment: @Buraian My last answer is not right. I edit this new one.

Comment: I mean this is fine, and I think result makes sense but I do not understand how this explains why the tension should act only at those two places for the rope

Comment: The tension in interior segament are canceled by draging in both direction, and the normal force are always perpendiculat to the rope.

Comment: Oh now it makes sense, but now that I look at it again, what exactly is the significance of the normal force being constant throughout length?

Comment: To me, it is the only way to make each point of the rope to have zero total force, during the cureved region.

Comment: This analysis you have done is for a non accelerating rope, correct? @ytlu However it seems like same should happen even if tension is varying as we don't see rope flying out from pulley, why is htis?

Comment: @Buraian No, Not for non accelerating rope, but for massless rope. Since $\Delta m = 0$ for each segment of rope, the total foce of each segment must be sero. It can have accleration, but not the force $F_{rope} = 0 \times a = 0$; Acceleration is ok, but force is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

When analyzing pulley systems we do not normally take into account the force of the loop on top of the pulley. We would use the tension of the rope on each side of the pulley. Discounting small frictions in the pulley and rope, the tension is the same throughout the rope. So pulley A has rope tension on each side for a total downward force of 2T.

Comment: You've just restated the problem without any explanation of why we are doing it..

Comment: Secondly how does a vertical segment of rope apply a vertical tension? You can only 'push down' on the pulley , you can't pull it downward

Comment: If you were able to correctly compute the total force of the rope across the top half of pulley A you will find it equals 2T, that is why we use tension. And how can vertical rope tension not apply vertical force?  A rope pulls with tension, it does not push.

Comment: I mean if the vertical segment 'pulls', then that'd generate a horizontal force, not a vertical one because the pulling must be perpendicular to the length imo. Secondly, can you describe how to go about 'correctly computing' it?