# What is direction of tension at the extrema end of the pulley which it curves around?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

Following from this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/607201/236734), we see that tension switches direction after we cross the top most point of the pulley. Ok, so this is fine that tension points in opposite direction (horizontally) after crossing top most point, but what exactly is tension at exactly the top most point of the pulley?

I know that there must be 'some' tension at a mass segment at the top most point because tension is constant throughout the rope, but I can't imagine the direction.

Comment: You are confusing tension with the force due to tension, or tensile force.  With no friction in a pulley system, the tension is constant everywhere along the rope.  Tension does not switch direction on either side of the pulley because it has no direction.  Force has a direction.

Answer (score 5):

Tension is a scalar and has no direction.

The tension in a segment of a "light" rope (and with a light or unaccelerating pulley) is created by a force of the same magnitude from each end.  The forces are always in the same direction as the rope.  For one over a pulley, it will be tangent to the pulley.

So the segment at the top of the pulley has forces on it from the adjoining rope segments on the left and right.  These forces are pulling nearly horizontally on the segment with forces equal to the tension in the rope.

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing this answer because usually, when in textbooks, when we hold a rope it is shown as the rope is apply a force opposite direction to which we pull it

Comment: How is that inconsistent with this answer?  If you imagine a tiny segment at the top, it is pulled from each side by the neighbors and it applies a counter force on those neighbors in the opposite direction.

Comment: Good answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be 0. Although the magnitude on the both side is constant the direction changes at the topmost point. Resultant tension at topmost point will be 0.  A very good example will be assuming that the rope is touching the pulley at one point only(the topmost point). Will the pulley rotate? I don't think so. So the net force due to tension is zero at that topmost point.

Answer (score 1):

While ytlu's answer is nice, I want to point out something also considering BowlOfRed's answer.

Summing up:

-if the rope is massless, the tension at the top has no orientation.

-if the rope has some mass, the tension points in the direction of its acceleration (and it can be 0 if the rope is not moving).

Divide the rope into infinitesimal pieces of mass $dm$. On each piece, there's going to be two forces acting, one on each side of the piece (we are assuming tension is always *along* the rope as there is where the rope extendes/contracts). We call them $T_1$ and $T_2$. There also is an external force $dmgcos(\theta)$ (gravity) where $\theta$ is some angle with respect to the vertical line (if the rope is vertical, $\theta=0$).

This means, that for the infinitesimal piece we can write

$$T_1+T_2+dmg=dm*a$$

now, in the *massless* rope assumption (the usual one) $dm=0$ so gravity vanishes and one gets $T_1=-T_2$. This holds at each point. So you see, the *total* tension acting on the small piece is 0, because it is the sum of two identical forces oriented differently on the two sides of the piece.

So what BowlOfRed means in saying that tension is a scalar is that *at each point of the rope* the tension is the same and has no direction: for each piece tension is the same left and right, otherwise the rope would not follow Newton's equation (in the massless asumption!).
Tension is actually a force, thus a vector (!!!), but it is balanced by the exact same vector with the same magnitued $|T_1|=|T_2|=T$ at each point so we can treat it *as if* it was a scalar. At every point is has a value ($T$) but no direction (actually, there's both directions!).

*However* - and here is the important part - this does *not* hold at the extremes where you have on one side the tension $T$ (still the same value ($T$) pointing *along the rope* and on the other side an external force (e.g. the weight of the mass attached to the rope, pointing downwards).
This is why tension is usually drawn as an arrow (a vector) opposite to the mass, despite having this "scalar" property.

So in an approximation where the tension is constant and in both direction, this also holds at the top of the pulley: the tension over there is $T$ and is oriented in both directions.

If otherwise the rope *has* some mass the tension is going to be given *as a vector* by the difference between the left and the right tension $T_1$ and $T_2$ which now are not equal anymore. This is because now the local tension has to balance *both* the outside force given by the weight *AND* the weight of the rope itself and of course the closer you go to the extremes of the rope, the less weight due to the rope you have at the bottom: while the bottom-most part only has to balance the outside weight, the topmost has to balance *both* the outside weight and the rope's weight: so the tension changes depending on the position i.e. there is a net tension at each point of the rope (so now it is a vector).

You can find the exact result for the top, solving the (vector) equation for a small piece of rope of mass $dm$ (we choose the piece on the top)

$$T=T_1-T_2=dm a$$
where $T_1$ is balancing the weight on the left (both outside weight *and* rope's weight) and $T_2$ is balancing the weight on the right. If they are in equilibrium, $T=0$ (so *no* tension at all on the top). If one is higher, then higher mass will move towards the bottom and the tension is going to have the direction of motion of the rope (because $T=dma$ so it has the same direction as the acceleration). So:  tangent to the pulley and oriented left/right depending on the masses it is holding. If the system is at equilibrium (a=0) then $T=0$.

Notice that this also means that the *only* equilibrium is when the two masses not only are equal, but they are at the exact same height, as otherwise there would be more weight due to the rope on one side than the other i.e. there would be a net force. On the contrary, in the ideal massless case (or if there is friction, other story) then the masses can be at equilibrium at different heights because the rope is massless and the tension is the same everywhere (no net force = no acceleration).

In a simple symmetrical example where you have a rope of length $L$ and constant linear mass density $\lambda$ across a (point-like) pulley with no friction holding two masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ at the two sides on the top, that the tension pushing on the left is going to be
$$T_1=M_1g+\lambda L_1 g$$
(where $L_1$ is the portion of rope on the left), and on the right you have
$$T_1=M_2g+\lambda(L-L_1)g$$
so that the net tension is going to be given by
$$T=T_2-T_1=(M_1-M_2)g+\lambda(2L_1-L)g$$
so it's zero if $M_1=M_2$ and $L_1=L/2$ and otherwise it has a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had revised my previous answer which the OP shared the link. I would write a short new version here. Please refer to the link for the Figure.

Consider a infinitesimal  segment of the rope around the wheel from angle $\theta$ to $\theta + d\theta$. The total force acting on this infinitesimal segment has to be $zero$, since we neglect the mass of the rope. The three forces on it are:

- tangential force at $\theta$:  -$T \hat{\theta}(\theta)$  (int negative tangential direction)
- tangential force at  $\theta + d\theta$: $T \hat{\theta}(\theta + d \theta)$
- Normal force from the wheel: $N(\theta) d\theta \hat{r}$, where $N(\theta)$ the normal force per angle.

The vector sum of these threee forces vanishes:

$$
    T ( \hat{\theta}(\theta + d \theta) - \hat{\theta}(\theta) ) + N(\theta) d\theta \hat{r} = 0; \\
  N(\theta)\hat{r} = -T  \frac{ \hat{\theta}(\theta + d \theta) - \hat{\theta}(\theta) }{ d\theta } = -T \frac{d \hat{\theta}}{d\theta} = T \hat{r}.
$$

The derivative of $\hat{r}$ by $\theta$ results $-\hat{r}$. Therefore, the magnitude of the normal force $N(\theta) = T$, a constant independent of angle. A resonable surprising answer.